# Embedding webpage page not working. (using IFrame)

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

So I'm trying to get this code to work, I've tried for awhile. For some reason it will not show my Twitter account, nor any other page.

```
<iframe src="URL" width="90%" height="350">
Error: Embedded data could not be displayed. 
</iframe>
```

Is something wrong with it? If for some reason IFrames no longer work, is there a "better" way of doing it?

Again, what I'm trying to do is embed my Twitter account onto my website.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine - but it does not seem to work for Twitter or Google... it works fine for other websites such as Wikipedia.org though...

You could use the Twitter API for timelines in order to embed the latest tweets of your Twitter account into your website: https://dev.twitter.com/web/embedded-timelines

Answer (score 0):

you can both use twitter API or any other API for the relevant link you want...another option is to do emband for a specific thing like a post/video or another thing like in FB for example:
[image]